# Is server code running continuously or only when a user makes a request?

Tags: html, rest

If I have a Golang server that contains code for HTTP requests and a user makes an HTTP request, do they get their own instance of the server code? Or is the same code shared between every user that makes a request?

Lets say my server code has a function that increments a value by one each time the user makes a GET request. If 100 users make one request, would that value be 100 or just 1 for each user? If its the former, how does it work when thousands of people make requests? Do they have to wait their turn in line to receive a response back from the server?

Comment: That depends on how you write your server code.

Comment: What language are you talking about here for the server?

Comment: There is no one answer to this question, because different technologies (languages, frameworks, hosting systems) are architected in different ways.